# Google Calendar timezone issue

Tags: jquery, json, date, datepicker, google-calendar-api

I'm integrating the Google Calendar API with jQuery DatePicker.

My code works fine on every browser except Internet Explorer, as usual.

I currently have this code:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json", function(data, textStatus){
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(index, event){
        if(event.gd$when) {
            var event_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', new Date(event.gd$when[0].startTime));
            if (!(calendar_data.hasOwnProperty(event_date))) {
                calendar_data[event_date] = new Array();
            }
            event.gd$when[0].formatedTime = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', new Date(event.gd$when[0].startTime));
            calendar_data[event_date].push(event);
        }
    });
    showEvent(new Date());

    $('#calendar-datepicker').datepicker("refresh");
});
```

It doesn't work in IE because IE uses the client's timezone to import dates.

Dates from Google Calendar aren't in the local timezone. I've seen that I can add a `ctz` (custom timezone) to my JSON call, but I can't find any information on it. It's not the timezone offset, [I know that much](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters).

My problem: Internet Explorer can't fetch Google Calendar dates. How can I fix this?

Comment: Word + Maths + In + Title = Silly title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... drop IE support? screw lame users!
I know this is a terrible answer but I'd still vote it up if I see it...

On a serious note, can't you open an exception for ie and account for the math?

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(event.gd$when[0].startTime)` returns NAN, based on browser

so change

```
var event_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', new Date(event.gd$when[0].startTime));
```

to

```
var event_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', Date.parse(event.gd$when[0].startTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you manage to get timezoneID of those Google Calendar? If yes then you are set to go. You can convert it.